# What was the purpose of the "strange crow mask" during the Black Death?

Tags: black-death

I looked at the Costumes which the doctors used during the Plague and saw that they wore a strange crow mask what is the reason for this? The mask does not provide any special protection as far as I see and the face itself serves no special purpose maybe apart from identification.

The [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plague_doctor_costume) also has not special information about the mask.

Comment: See the accepted answer to [‘Avoid sleeping on your back’ & ‘breathe in toilet smells’ were seen as precautions against the Black Death. Why did doctors think these would work?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/41021/avoid-sleeping-on-your-back-breathe-in-toilet-smells-were-seen-as-precauti).

Comment: Thanks a lot @LarsBosteen